# Can't run SDL2 executable by double-click

Tags: c, executable, sdl-2, double-click

## Hello :)

I am presently learning SDL2, and I made several programs with it. 
With these programs, when I double-click on the executable, the program launches, and everything is okay. 
On the last program I made, it doesn't work anymore. With this one, I can only launch from terminal. 
The exe has the permissions, so theres no reason for this to happen...

The only thing I changed is that the old generic function file I used (for things like "loadTextureFromImage()"...) to a dynamic library I created. Here's a link to the entire project (just a white window for now) -> [RightHere](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8rxek3jYbexWm5sdDdTbno2dDg/view?usp=sharing).

I'm currently running Ubuntu 14.04.

If you have any idea on why it doesn't work just for THIS project, tell me please!

Thank you in advance ;)

PS : Here's a project that actually works -> [RightHere](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8rxek3jYbexbVZMSnFFSFIxcTQ/view?usp=sharing)

PS2 : The projects are in c

---

Okay, so I did `ldd ./myprog`, and the libraries linked are where I put them, in "${HOME}/lib". If I understood well, you are telling me that because these libraries aren't in "/usr/lib and so on...", they won't be found, and I should write a script. There's a little thing I forgot to tell : I had to add an environment variable in my .bashrc -> `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${HOME}/lib`, so that the libraries are found at compile-time. Because of what you said, I think that this variable is only loaded in terminals, isn't it? So I tried two scripts :

```
#!/bin/bash

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PWD

./myprog
```

(like you told) and

```
#!/bin/bash

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${HOME}/lib

./myprog
```

(like I made in my .bashrc).

When I run them by double-clicking on them, neither work.
But, when I run them from terminal, only the second one works.

Thank you for the answer, hope it'll help...

EDIT : I confirm that the variable set in .bashrc are only loaded in terminals : I tested this script ->

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH > Run.log

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${HOME}/lib

echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH >> Run.log

./Pong
```

and, when I run it from terminal, Run.log contains this :

`/home/yohan/lib
/home/yohan/lib`,

but, when I run it from double-click, it only contains

`*newline*
/home/yohan/lib`

Comment: Don't think many people will fetch your code file-by-file, I certainly wouldn't; if it would'be been at least an archive I might have looked into it. Try writing message into some log by absolute path, maybe it does start but you just don't see it. If not, you should add additional info like at least what OS you use. If everything else fails, there is always strace (or procmon as windows alternative).

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I tried writing in a file, but again, it does work only when it runs from terminal :/

Comment: There are so many things that can be messed up to produce this situation - so I can only guess. If you say you added a link to new library, then most logical answer is that this library isn't reachable in given environment. Run `ldd ./your_program` and see where resolved libraries located. If your libraries are placed in e.g. programs directory (instead of system `/usr/lib` and so on - specified in `/etc/ld.so.conf`), then you usually can't use that directly and have to write a shell script that sets `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PWD` and then runs your program, or use rpath.

Comment: You're supposed to edit your question if you have something new to say. Answer-that-isnt-an-answer is predictably downvoted. Anyway, add `export` before your variable setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Add export before your variable setting. – keltar

Okay so thank you VERY much, it works now, with this script :

```
#!/bin/bash

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${HOME}/lib

./myprog
```